# Scatterplot in Matplotlib with its natural line

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

While joining the points given by scatterplot in matplotlib, I only want to get the natural fit, and not x-y , which becomes a zig-zag as shown below.

How can I do this in matpotlib ?

PS: I don't want fitting polynomial/regression line, just the regular natural line

```
from pylab import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

//Generate some x-y data for yourself...
x=[key for key in my_dict.keys()]
y=[imp for imp in my_dict.values()]
xlim([min(x),max(x)])
ylim([min(y),max(y)])
plt.scatter(x,y)
```

I get :

[image]

On doing basic plot along with this, I get connected, but overlapping lines

```
plt.plot(x, y, '-o')
plt.show()
```

[image]

What I would like to have:

[image]

Related [q/a](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6328138/scatterplot-instead-of-a-lineplot-while-using-the-plotfile-function-of-matplotlib) but doesn't exactly fit my case

Fallback Alternatives  - Fit a n-th degrees polynomial as here -
[Multivariate (polynomial) best fit curve in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856206/multivariate-polynomial-best-fit-curve-in-python)

**Edit :**- I tried the code below as suggested

```
[x, y] = zip(*sorted(zip(x, y), key=lambda x: x[0])) ###
plt.plot(x, y, '-o')
```

here's what I now get, butI am looking for something more smoother.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In order for `plt.plot(x, y, '-o')` to work, you will need to sort your data in x so that the line doesn't appear disjointed. You can do that with something like this:

```
[x, y] = zip(*sorted(zip(x, y), key=lambda x: x[0]))
```

That will sort both data, with x as the key.

Comment: Not one of the best, but this works.I was looking for something "smoother" (I guess I will need polyfit there?).Edited my question with your suggestion & plot I now see .Thanks.

Comment: ekta, I think you did something wrong (or maybe the comment was wrong. I guess what pseudocubic was saying is that you need to sort x-values of your data and for each sorted x plot corresponding y(x). This operation should not change your scatter plot at all. All you are doing is that plot function connects the points one by one

Comment: I just tried pseudocubic solution and it worked perfectly for me. Try converting your data to numpy array - maybe that'll help.